# How to go to "next" object in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am creating an admin interface in which the user will have a button **Save and go to next**. I would like that button to move to the next item in the admin change list, **respecting the queryset in the list** - ie, the user could perform a search, make filters, change the ordering and start at the top of the list and work his/her way down.

This is what I have to implement:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = ['mymodel-savenext.html']

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        """Determines the HttpResponse for the change_view stage."""
        if '_save_next' in request.POST:
            # -> How do I get the queryset in the original order and find `obj` it it?
            nextobj = ?
            return redirect('admin:app_mymodel_admin', nextobj.id)
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

Please consider the queryset may be large. If the user would go directly into the changeform url (pasting a URL for example), it would make sense to redirect him back to the list or assume a "default" ordering, like getting the next ID.

Comment: When you click on an object from the list to open its change view, the `request` has `GET` parameters that allow the django admin to go back to the same list, such as `_changelist_filters` (look at the URL when selecting an object). Maybe that can help you construct the queryset. Although fetching the "next in line" isn't an easy task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two difficulties in doing this:

1. To assemble the **same queryset** used to list the objects, and
2. Possibly modifying this queryset to obtain only the object following the current one (without having to iterate through all of it).

**As for the first:** Django saves the parameters used to generate the list in a GET parameter called `_changelist_filters`, but this argument is not used by `changeform_view`. It is only "restored" as GET parameters when returning to the list. In order to use this argument, we must change the `HttpRequest` (which sounds bad) so we can create an instance of `django.contrib.admin.views.main.ChangeList` - the object that will process these filters and generate the queryset.

**Secondly**, to find a primary key in the middle of a query that may be ordered by any other field, I found no other solution other than to perform a linear search through the query itself. *(Perhaps someone can shed some light in this.)*

The result is this mixin to add to the `ModelAdmin` class:

```
from django.http import QueryDict


class GotoNextAdminMixin(object):

    def get_next_instance_pk(self, request, current):
        """Returns the primary key of the next object in the query (considering filters and ordering).
        Returns None if the object is not in the queryset.
        """
        querystring = request.GET.get('_changelist_filters')
        if querystring:
            # Alters the HttpRequest object to make it function as a list request
            original_get = request.GET
            try:
                request.GET = QueryDict(querystring)
                # from django.contrib.admin.options: ModelAdmin.changelist_view
                ChangeList = self.get_changelist(request)
                list_display = self.get_list_display(request)
                changelist = ChangeList(
                    request, self.model, list_display,
                    self.get_list_display_links(request, list_display),
                    self.get_list_filter(request),
                    self.date_hierarchy,
                    self.get_search_fields(request),
                    self.get_list_select_related(request),
                    self.list_per_page,
                    self.list_max_show_all,
                    self.list_editable,
                    self,
                    self.sortable_by)  # New in Django 2.0
                queryset = changelist.get_queryset(request)
            finally:
                request.GET = original_get
        else:
            queryset = self.get_queryset(request)

        # Try to find pk in this list:
        iterator = queryset.values_list('pk', flat=True).iterator()
        try:
            while next(iterator) != current.pk:
                continue
            return next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            pass # Not found or it was the last item
```

Then in my ModelAdmin class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, GotoNextAdminMixin):

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        """Determines the HttpResponse for the change_view stage."""
        if '_save_next' in request.POST:
            next_pk = self.get_next_instance_pk(request, obj)
            if next_pk:
                response = redirect('admin:app_mymodel_change', next_pk)
                qs = request.GET.urlencode()  # keeps _changelist_filters
            else:
                # Last item (or no longer in list) - go back to list in the same position
                response = redirect('admin:app_mymodel_changelist')
                qs = request.GET.get('_changelist_filters')

            if qs:
                response['Location'] += '?' + qs
            return response

        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

Drawbacks of this approach:

- Must alter the variable HttpRequest.GET. In current Django version, it's not a property, so it's changeable, but in the future it may not be so.
- Must iterate through the whole queryset (although we only retrieve PKs) - bad for large tables or costly queries.
- Only works for models with a single-field primary key (as most things in Django, so it may not be a problem).
- If the object is no longer in the list (for example there was a filter and the current object was filtered out), the effort was wasted.

Pros:

- It works!

Comment: Great write-up, but it's unfortunate this isn't easier.

Answer (score -1):

In admin.py

```
class YourModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
  def response_change(self, request, obj):
    while True:
        return redirect(f'/admin/viewer/{obj._meta.model_name}/{obj.id + 1}/change/')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).